# Undefined symbol: _FlutterDefaultDartEntrypoint - Adding a Flutter screen to an iOS app and using initialRoute

Tags: swift, flutter, flutter-add-to-app

The official [Adding a Flutter screen to an iOS app](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/ios/add-flutter-screen?tab=engine-swiftui-tab#route) documentation suggests that starting with Flutter version 1.22, an initial route can be set for Flutter when constructing the FlutterViewController:

```
let flutterEngine = FlutterEngine()
// FlutterDefaultDartEntrypoint is the same as nil, which will run main().
engine.run(
  withEntrypoint: FlutterDefaultDartEntrypoint, initialRoute: "/onboarding")
```

But when following these instructions, the build fails with an error:

```
Undefined symbol: _FlutterDefaultDartEntrypoint
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment in the above code example suggests, *"FlutterDefaultDartEntrypoint is the same as nil, which will run main"*.

So substituting `FlutterDefaultDartEntrypoint` with `nil` solves the issue:

```
let flutterEngine = FlutterEngine()
engine.run(withEntrypoint: nil, initialRoute: "/onboarding")
```

For running anything other than the default `main()` method, the following can be used:

```
let flutterEngine = FlutterEngine()
engine.run(
    withEntrypoint: "otherMain",
    libraryURI: "other_file.dart",
    initialRoute: "/onboarding"
)
```

This will look for an `otherMain()` method in the `other_file.dart` file.